# React styleguidist ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I added react styleguidist to my project. Now when running npm run styleguidist, an error occurs ReferenceError: process is not defined

My styleguide.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    title: 'Style Guide',
    pagePerSection: true,

    sections: [{
            name: 'components',
            sectionDepth: 1,
            components: './src/components/button.jsx'
        },

    ],

}
```

Comment: Where is `process` in this code snippet?

Comment: in my webpack.config.js

Answer (score 1):

Given that you added no explanation about your setup, I'm going to make many assumptions in my response.
Which version of webpack are you using? I think it might be related to v5 because it no longer uses process dependency while `styleguidist` still relies on v4 which does.

You can solve the issue temporarily by updating your webpack config:

```
plugins:[
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    process: { env: {} }
  })
]
```